# If statement Swift

Tags: swift, function, if-statement

I have a function with "on success" and "on failure" cases.

```
func loadBanners(nameId: String, onSuccess: @escaping (_ objectArray: [IGCBanners]) -> (), onFailure: @escaping (NSError) -> ()) {
    IGCTransactionManager.sharedInstance.getBanners(
        nameId: nameId,
        onSuccess: { json in
            if let json = json {
                let res: IGCBannersRootClass = IGCBannersRootClass(fromJson: json)
                
                self.populate(res)
                
                if nameId == "home" {
                    self.populateSlideShow(res)
                }
                
                onSuccess(TransactionSession.shared.Array)
            } else {
                onFailure(IGCTransactionManager.sharedInstance.getErrorForNil())
            }
        },
```

When it goes on failure, I would like to check if it's the first time.
So If its first, I need to reload the success case and from second time (else) to shows invalid-failure case.

```
onFailure: { error in
            if  error == true {
                self.loadBanners(nameId: "home", onSuccess: onSuccess, onFailure: onFailure)
            } else {
                if !self.showInvalidResponse(onSuccess: onSuccess, onFailure: onFailure) {
                    onFailure(error)
                }
            }
        }
```

My condition error == true ,Its not the right one for sure and I think doesn't explain that this is happened for first time. Any advice or recommend ?

Comment: `onFailure: @escaping (NSError) -> ()`, so `error` is clearly not a boolean. But this seems irrelevant to what you want to do, if you want to check if something is the first time you need to keep some state that you can update once the first time has occurred such as using a boolean property or argument to your function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to HangarRash comment I solved with a counter

```
var failurecounter = 0
```

this outside the function and inside the onfailure case

```
self.failureCounter += 1
        if self.failureCounter == 1 { ... }
```